# Is there a way to print a list with each item placed under the last in python?

Tags: python, list, formatting

I am able to print a list so each item appears underneath the last, but how would I put this format into a variable? For example, if I had a list and a for loop:

```
a = ["item one", "item two", "item three"]
for item in a:
    print(item)
```

I would get this:

```
item one
item two
item three
```

How would I put this format into a variable so I could run the variable and get this format?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you just want to put those three strings into one variable. You could just use `\n` for that:

```
msg = "item one\nitem two\nitem three"
```

or maybe vene `"""..."""`

Answer (score 0):

```
result = "\n".join(a)
```

---

*The explanation:*

The `.join()` method joins all elements in your list into string, delimiting them with the string for which this method is applied — in our case with the string (the newline symbol) `"\n"`.

---

So in the result variable will be the string `"item one\nitem two\nitem three"`.

You may prove it with the help of the `repr()` function:

```
print(repr(result))
```

> ```
> 'item one\nitem two\nitem three'
> ```

and if we will print it with the common `print(result)` command, every `\n` symbol will be interpreted as a line break:

> ```
> item one
> item two
> item three
> ```